# p_thread set thread name not showing up in htop

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu-16.04

I have a multi-threaded C application and I would like to set the thread names so that they show up in tools such as htop.

I am creating the threads

```
pthread_create(&q->threads[i].thread, NULL, worker, &q->threads[i]);
//q->threads[i].thread is a pthread_t object, 
//and q->threads[i] is the arg passed to worker.
```

and in the worker function I have

```
pthread_t self = pthread_self();
snprintf(name, 16, "worker-%d", data->id);
printf("The name to be set is %s\n", name);
int res = pthread_setname_np(self, name);
printf("setname returned %d\n", res);
char thread_name[16];
res = pthread_getname_np(self, thread_name, 16);
printf("Get name returned %d and shows the name is '%s'\n", res, thread_name);
```

When I run the code, I get

```
The name to be set is worker-1
setname returned 0
Get name returned 0 and shows the name is 'worker-1'
```

for each of my worker threads (the names are of the form worker-X)

However, when I view the results in htop (I have set htop to show the thread tree), all the threads show up with the parent program name.

There is no other code that references the thread name anywhere, so I can't see where that is being reset. I also looked in /proc/{PID} and the thread names are set wrong in there also. So, I believe that it is an issue with my code, but I cannot figure it out.

I am running Ubuntu 16. I am also using CMake, but I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Did you enable `htop`s "Show custom thread names" option? And possibly "Update process names on every refresh"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a filter in htop, and that was hiding my named threads. Once I removed that filter, it showed.